# SerialPort timeouts in ReadChar() method, WPF, "The operation has timed out."

Tags: wpf, serial-port, timeout

Goal of my program is to send data to the RS232 and read them in with a different function. I have a direct connection (wire) between the RS232 pin 2 and pin 3.
I'm getting randomly occurring timeouts in WPF when I'm reading the serial port, but I receive the data and can print it.

Create a serial port and a delegate in my class.

```
        SerialPort _serialPort;
        `public delegate void ReceiveData(object sender);`
```

Create a SerialDataReceivedEventHandler after InitializeComponent()
`_serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialPort1_DataReceive);`

Define method for event.

```
        private void SerialPort1_DataReceive(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ReceiveData(OutputDataToList), sender);
        }
```

Define method for the delegate.

```
        private void OutputDataToList(object sender)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            _inChar = '1';
            while (_inChar != '\n')
            {
                try
                {
                    _inChar = (char)sp.ReadChar();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error while receiving the serial port. " + ex.Message);
                    break; 
                }
                if (_inChar != '\n')
                {
                    _inMessage += _inChar;
                }
            }
            if (_inMessage != "")
            {
                lstReads.Items.Add(_inMessage);
                lstReads.SelectedIndex = lstReads.Items.Count - 1;
            }
            _inMessage = "";
        }
```

In 70%-90% of the tests, the program works fine but sometimes, this error occurs:

[image]

I changed the timeout time. It gets better (but still happens sometimes) for shorter time but I don't understand why.

```
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
```

Comment: All my serial port adventures included examining ".BytesToRead" as a sanity check. (among other things).

Comment: It's very possible that you're triggering a `OutputDataToList` that is processing the data of the next "batch" of data that triggers the `SerialPort_DataReceived` event. For example, you get an event that receives 10 bytes, but you process 20 bytes because data appears in the serial port buffer while you're processing it from the first event. Then when the second event triggers, there's no data to process.